# Powershell API only process orders that have a specific role name

Tags: powershell

I have created a script that Gets order status (processing) & to filter to a specific user role. The problem i am having is even though i have a customer order that is processing & the role equals public it still doesn't run. please see below the beginning of my script that shows these filters. i have left out the API Keys for obvious reasons.

```
# API endpoint to get processing orders
$OrderEndpoint = "/wp-json/wc/v3/orders"
$OrderQueryParameters = "?status=processing"  # Adjust this parameter as needed

# API endpoint to get customers with the "invoice" role
$CustomerEndpoint = "/wp-json/wc/v3/customers"
$CustomerQueryParameters = "?role=public"  # Adjust this parameter as needed

# Construct the URLs
$OrderUrl = $StoreUrl + $OrderEndpoint + $OrderQueryParameters
$CustomerUrl = $StoreUrl + $CustomerEndpoint + $CustomerQueryParameters

# Generate a timestamp for the request
$TimeStamp = [System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

# Generate a nonce (a random string)
$Nonce = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString("N")

# Combine the API key, timestamp, and nonce to create the signature
$Signature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("${ApiKey}:${ApiSecret}"))

# Create headers for the request
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Basic " + $Signature
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    "X-WC-Date" = $TimeStamp
    "X-WC-Nonce" = $Nonce
}

# Execute a GET request to the WooCommerce API to get processing orders
$orders = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $OrderUrl -Headers $headers -Method Get

# Execute a GET request to the WooCommerce API to get customers with the "invoice" role
$invoiceCustomers = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $CustomerUrl -Headers $headers -Method Get

# Extract customer user IDs from invoice customers
$invoiceCustomerUserIds = $invoiceCustomers | ForEach-Object { $_.id }
```

as you can see have filtered the orders to processing and the role to public

i then have created a foreach loop to go through all orders that meat this criteria, again this is just a snippet

```
# Iterate through the orders and process each one
foreach ($order in $orders) {
    try {
        # Check if the order is in "processing" status
        if ($order.status -eq "processing" -and $invoiceCustomerUserIds -contains $order.customer_id) {
```

i thought initially to add the role to the if statement but it seems the only way i can get the role is to take it from the array for instance.

```
 if ($order.status -eq "processing" -and $invoiceCustomerUserIds -contains $order.customer_id -and $invoicecustomers[0].role -eq "public")
```

which given it does run but the problem being is it also tries to post Invoice and Cashcustomers Roles which is not what i want to achieve.

I basically want to say if role equals public run else do nothing but i cant figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: It would be easier if you create a [mcve] with an example of the `$Orders` and `$invoiceCustomers` (`json`) objects. Anyhow, I guess you somehow want to join the `$orders` the with the `$invoiceCustomers` list which usually requires a nested loop (or a lookup table). See: [what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1848821/1701026). Using this [JoinModule](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) it would probably something like: `$orders | Join-Object $invoiceCustomers -on customer_id -eq id`

Comment: @iRon thank you for your response, i have now figured this out but again thank you for taking your time to post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my issue i had to create a new `URL` and put that into my foreach loop with me doing this the `variable` `$customer` could now get the role and do its `if` statement. Below is the working snippet.

```
# API endpoint to get customers with the "invoice" role
$CustomerEndpoint = "/wp-json/wc/v3/customers"
$CustomerQueryParameters = "?role=cashinvoice"  # Adjust this parameter as needed

# Construct the URLs
$OrderUrl = $StoreUrl + $OrderEndpoint + $OrderQueryParameters
$CustomerUrl = $StoreUrl + $CustomerEndpoint + $CustomerQueryParameters
$CustomerUrl2 = $StoreUrl + $CustomerEndpoint


# Iterate through the orders and process each one
foreach ($order in $orders) {
    try {
       # Execute a GET request to retrieve customer information based on customer_id
        $customer = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$CustomerUrl2/$($order.customer_id)" -Headers $headers -Method Get

        # Check if the customer has a role equal to "public"
        if ($customer.role -eq "public") {
            # Check if the order is in "processing" status
            if ($order.status -eq "processing") {

#Rest of the script
}
```

Comment: That is **very expensive** as you will `Invoke-RestMethod` for every `$Order`, I really recommend you to look into the answers listed here: [In PowerShell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)

Comment: Always up for learning new ways I will definitely check it out

Comment: This article might help you: [PowerShell scripting performance considerations / Looking up entries by property in large collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations#looking-up-entries-by-property-in-large-collections)